# asp.net core routing issue http 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I am trying to simulate an arcgis web service and have created a simple ASP.NET MVC application.

My site is using the default route mapping

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

My controller is defined as this with no specific route

`public class ESRIController : Controller`

My method in the controller is defined as

```
[Route("/arcgis/rest/services/{serviceName}/FeatureServer/{layerId}")]
public IActionResult FeatureServerLayer(string serviceName, int layerId, Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>? queryString)
{}
```

If I call this method like this there is no issue

```
http://localhost:5047/arcgis/rest/services/Landsdowne/FeatureServer/0
```

But if the function is called like this then it results in an HTTP 500 server error

```
http://localhost:5047/arcgis/rest/services/Landsdowne/FeatureServer/0?f=json
```

[image: Http500ServerError]

My function is never called. The error occurs somewhere in the ASP.NET Core runtime.

Using Chrome to view the request also shows no more information.

[image: Chrome Output]

There is no other response shown in chrome.

Comment: What is the error when you debug it in Visual Studio?

Comment: Anyway why do you think adding this: f=json it will work?

Comment: the f=json is what arcgis javascript adds to the url when my code is called.

Comment: No error is triggered in Visual Studio. My method never gets called. I assume the error is consumed by the .net core runtime

Comment: You can breakpoint the injection of the mvc that triggers the 500

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did not mention in the original post was this was a .NET Core 6 application under Visual Studio 2022.

I created a new .NET Core 5 application and no error is caused and my method is called properly.

I created another new .NET CORE 6 MVC application and no error is caused and my method is called properly.

The only difference with the two application that works and the one that does not is that the one that does not work is hosted in IIS on my development machine (not IIS Express). I previously installed the .NET Core 6 hosting bundle so I can debug from a remote machine via IIS which I could not do with IIS Express.

So it looks like the IIS Hosting may be to blame. I will need to test on a production server to determine if this is still going to be an issue.

But I need it hosted in IIS on my dev machine as the arcgis rest api's are being called from the Internet and my dev machine is inside a corporate firewall. I am using NGROK as a tunnel from the internet to my machine. Maybe I can configure IIS to answer remote connections?